# Dynamically created href attributes in C#

Tags: c#, hyperlink

This is the C# code used to create a link to google

```
href.Controls.Add(Image);
href.Attributes.Add("href", "www.google.com");
href.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
href.Attributes.Add("title", "Click To Follow The Link");
```

however when I click it, the url it takes me to is this

```
http://localhost:52647/Mywebsite/www.google.co.za
```

any ideas on how I make it go straight to google?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using an ASP:Hyperlink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try prefixing it with http://

```
href.Controls.Add(Image);
href.Attributes.Add("href", "http://www.google.com");
href.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
href.Attributes.Add("title", "Click To Follow The Link");
```

Answer (score 1):

change href.Attributes.Add("href", "www.google.com"); to href.Attributes.Add("href", "http://www.google.com");